# Liquibase database autocomplete using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, liquibase

Is there a way to get autocomplete for columns and tables from my database in a changelog file ?

```
    <changeSet id="001" author="test">
        <insert tableName="person">
            <column name="id" valueComputed="seqPerson.NEXTVAL" />
            <column name="myName" value="test" />
        </insert>
        <rollback>
            DELETE FROM person WHERE myName='test';
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
```

In this example I would like to have autocomplete for *person*, *id*, *myName* and *seqPerson* (and the Rollback tag...).

Note that I already have the LiquiBase tags autocompletion working from the xsd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. You might look at Datical DB - it has a changeset wizard that provides this sort of functionality.

Disclaimer - I work for Datical.